# Chrome + Ace + Emmet

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, emmet

I have 0 understanding at the moment about the Chrome Experiments - CodeMirror and Ace editor. I've never used any of them.  There must be a good reason for chrome to experiment with adding them to Developer Tools.

I'd like to try them out, but I find that I'm so much used to Emmet in ST(2/3) that I can't write without it anymore.

Is there a way to get Emmet into Chrome Ace or Chrome Code Mirror editors ?

Comment: you can probably hack up the js version https://github.com/emmetio/textarea